# I have one live iOS app made with SwiftUI on App Store & I have made same app with Flutter. How to replace app on App Store?

Tags: flutter, swiftui, app-store, app-store-connect

I have one live iOS app made with SwiftUI on App Store & I have made the same app with Flutter. How to replace the SwiftUI app with the Flutter app on App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the same bundle identifier and a greater version than the iOS app on your Flutter app. Then you can just build your app and upload it the same way you would upload your iOS app.